# Android Studio / IntelliJ: Highlight custom strings in the log (or logcat)

Tags: android-studio, logging, intellij-idea, customization

Android and IntelliJ both have support for highlighting log messages based on the log level.
I'd like to go a step further and also highlight "my" classes, means classes from "my" packages - in a different way so that I can recognize them quickly in the log. So I'd like to see an option where I can define a custom string and then give lines which contain this string a custom highlighting. The "string" could be a package name, a debug string, or whatever.

Do you know if such a solution exists already? Maybe there's already a plugin for that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of anything specifically targeting this use case, but I have workarounds for you.

#### Search

Focus the LogCat window by clicking into it and the press <kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>, this brings up the local search bar and you can enter your package name:
[image: example log]

#### Filter logs

*This solution is from my question: [How can I disable Android's internal logging for specific tags (e.g. AbsListView, GestureDetector, endeffect)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19610151/253468)*
If you're having problems with spamming log lines you don't care about just filter them out, for example I have this configuration:

```
^(?!AbsListView|endeffect|GestureDetector|CustomFrequencyManager|ApplicationPackageManager|PersonaManager|ProgressBar|ViewRootImpl|MotionRecognitionManager)
^(?!Unable to resolve superclass of|Link of class|DexOpt: unable to opt direct call|Could not find class|Could not find method|VFY: )
```

[image: log filter]

This leaves only the most important/relevant log lines:

- your app's logs
- `dalvikvm`'s Garbage Collections
- `StrictMode`
- and other unexpected things

#### High-level logging

*I don't suggest you do this, included for completeness.* Use only `Log.wtf` and `Log.e` for your own logging and set colors/LogCat view's level filter accordingly. This is not really useful if you want to have 5 levels of logging. There may be some sneak-in log lines, but less than normal.

Answer (score 1):

What about the plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console.

I use it and it is quite good.