# Is there anyway to stop a Log message from being printed to the LogCat?

Tags: android, logging, overriding

Is there anyway to Override a Log message that's built into default implementation? Its just that in a ListView, there's this annoying Log that continuously gets called as you scroll through the ListView:

```
Time                    Tag                              Text
...                     ...                              ...
05-18 21:20:46.095:     AbsListView(2752):               unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-18 21:20:46.185:     AbsListView(2752):               unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-18 21:20:46.325:     AbsListView(2752):               unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-18 21:20:46.405:     AbsListView(2752):               unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-18 21:20:46.526:     AbsListView(2752):               unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-18 21:20:46.606:     AbsListView(2752):               unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-18 21:20:58.879:     AbsListView(2752):               unregisterIRListener() is called 
05-18 21:20:58.989:     IInputConnectionWrapper(2752):   showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-18 21:20:59.209:     AbsListView(2752):               onDetachedFromWindow
05-18 21:20:59.209:     FragmentPhotoGallery(2752):      Background thread destroyed
```

I'm thinking that the solution would be to find the method that its called in and Override it, leaving the Log.d() call out. Does anyone have any experience on this kind of thing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude certain messages by TAG name using Android adb logcat?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511433/how-to-exclude-certain-messages-by-tag-name-using-android-adb-logcat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click ["eclipse logging configuration document"](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging#How_To_Configure_Logging)!

But AFAIK you can totally turn it off, or set filter level to info, error, debug, warning...

There is no way to stop a specific set of errors from getting logged unless that is one of your own class and you could remove the logger code in it.