# Disable logs under my application if not explicitly called by my code

Tags: android, android-log

I want to clean up log entries that appear logcat as well as other tools that report calls to `Log.x()`, such as Crashlytics.

There are quite a few entries appearing that I did not explicitly create, that have my application's unique identifier (e.g. com.example.myapp). Some examples are tags like: `Adreno-EGL`, `MediaPlayer`, `jdwp`, `dalvikcm`, `Zygote`, `Crashlytics`, `OpenGLRenderer`.

Can I intercept and filter these? Or disable invocations outside of my code altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a filter on the top field of your logcat like app:. you can also filter by tag (tag: or even by anything you want to find within the messages (just type a phrase you want o filter by). There are also pid: that corresponds to process id (its helpful when youre filtering app which is already released / not in debug mode as there is no application tag visible).PS You just can't disable the logs permanently

Comment: Ok, fair enough, thanks. I guess I'll use this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511433/how-to-exclude-certain-messages-by-tag-name-using-android-adb-logcat