# android remove WebView debug logcat

Tags: android, webview

like this one

```
WebView  D  evaluateJavascript=blah blah
```

Can this be removed?

I tried use Proguard to remove Log, but only my logs are removed. WebView log still there.

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}
```

Edit: It's not about filtering log. I don`t want someone see the log when running my app, which more difficult to hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() 
{
   @Override
   public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage cm) {
      //Log.d("TAG", cm.message() + " at " + cm.sourceId() + ":" + cm.lineNumber());
      return true;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not remove log chat errors because you are seem your phone errors from logchat . You can remove just runtime errors from proguard.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use filtering? You can remove WebView tag so you don't see it in logcat, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29619376/how-to-exclude-log-tag-in-logcat-android-studio).