# Exclude Tag in Android Studio Logcat for a Log Level

Tags: logging, android-studio

A library I'm using in Android Studio is sending verbose messages at the Info level that I wish to exclude from Logcat, but I need to see messages at the Warning and Error levels.

```
09-16 21:45:54.430    6847-7125/com.aawhere.homeaware I/cmusphinx﹕ 2.30
09-16 21:45:54.430    6847-7125/com.aawhere.homeaware I/cmusphinx﹕ >
09-16 21:45:54.437    6847-7125/com.aawhere.homeaware I/cmusphinx﹕ INFO: fsg_search.c(843): 116 frames, 3674 HMMs (31/fr), 9363 senones (80/fr), 464 history entries (4/fr)
09-16 21:45:54.441    6847-6847/com.aawhere.homeaware E/cmusphinx﹕ ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 913: Final result does not match the grammar in fr
```

Excluding an entire Tag is [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14609392/721000), but that excludes all levels.

[image]

The above filter excludes all log entries shown above.  The desired result is:

```
09-16 21:45:54.441    6847-6847/com.aawhere.homeaware E/cmusphinx﹕ ERROR: "fsg_search.c", line 913: Final result does not match the grammar in fr
```

How can I exclude only **Info** level log entries for cmusphinx tagged log entries?

Comment: "so you want info debugging and exclude cmush?" No.  I want to exclude the info statements.  "The above image excludes logs for what ever level you require." That's what you'd expect, but it filters out Info and Error.

Comment: "What general level of debugging to you want for all else?" I only wish to target the overly verbose library. Everything else should stay the same.  "And you wan to exclude from verbose to info for cmush?" yes.