# Logcat reporting way too much stuff

Tags: android, logcat

The android logcat is logging way too much useless crap. I can't even see what I am logging from my code and therefore it get's so much harder to debug my application. I don't want the logcat to log things about my device. So how do I make it only log things from my code (Log.d(string, string))?

Comment: You can filter your logcat as described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931987/how-to-filter-logcat-in-android-studio

Comment: filter by adding package name

Comment: If the spam is from system calls in your own app (e.g., the "NativeCrypto" garbage logging that plagued 4.x devices), you can [exclude specific tags from logcat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14609392/1953590).

Comment: Related posts - [Filter LogCat to get only the messages from My Application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6854127/465053) & [How to filter logcat in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19931987/465053)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**one**

Click here.

[image: one]

**two**

[image: two]

**three**

For example for `Log.d("LogsAndroid", string)`

Where `"LogsAndroid"` it's a `TAG`

[image: three]

**four**

[image: four]

**Later you can choose here on dropdown what do you want to show**

[image: five]

Comment: I'm glad to listen that. @Someone

Comment: Could you (or someone) update this for the new logcat (2023)?

Comment: You can just write on the filter inbox whatever you need, Ex. if you need to control some tag, just write `Tag:MyTagName` @SMBiggs. And I recommend to you to have `package:mine` filter too. You can concatenate different needs. Ex. `package:mine tag:MyTagName`

Answer (score 1):

In Android studio as well as eclipse, there are are direct options in logcat to
1: Select your application package only to show logs related to your app only.
2: Select the desired Log level you want to see. Select 'Debug' if you want to view only 'Log.d' methods.