# How to handle the error message "FontFamily bestFont == NULL, so return vacant FakedFont"

Tags: android

I've taken over a project from another programmer, and I've noticed that every time some UI gets loaded (fragment, listview reload, etc), the log gets spammed with dozens of

```
D/Minikin: FontFamily bestFont == NULL, so return vacant FakedFont
```

messages.

Now, the app seems to work just fine, but it would be nice if I could solve the problem, so the log doesn't get spammed.

The app does use custom fonts, so that might have something to do with it, but I can't for the life of me see what might be wrong. The words "FontFamily", "bestFont" and "FakedFont" aren't used anywhere in the project.

Comment: if you can't find something with the words you said, have you tried to clean your project after the changes u've made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your app uses [this framework](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/minikin/), and it writes this message to logs. So, you can't remove that since it's not inside your code.

However, you can exclude lines with tag named `Minikin` from logcat. See the following for how to achieve that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29634795/5250273