# LogCat filtering - include and exclude at the same time

Tags: android, regex, logcat

I'd like to show logs that contain `MainActivity` but don't contain `ActivityManager`, so that this match is excluded:

```
I/ActivityManager: Start proc 2666:com.example.app/u0000 for activity {com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}
```

I tried as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30714755):

```
(?=(MainActivity))(?!(ActivityManager))
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/luhbDl/1) help?

Comment: "It didn't work" can mean many different things. Tell us specifically how the result differed from what you expected -- which often means that you have to explicitly say what you expected.

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of a single negative l lookaheadand, use an anchor `^` at the start of the string.

```
^(?!.*\bActivityManager\b).*\bMainActivity\b.*
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!.*\bActivityManager\b)` Negative lookahead, assert that `ActivityManager` is not present
- `.*\bMainActivity\b.*` Match the whole line with `bMainActivity`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LRu2DF/1)

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays you can [use keys to more surgically filter](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat#key-value-search) the logcat results. For the example you gave, you want to show log lines whose `message` contains `MainActivity`, and whose `tag` does *not* contain `ActivityManager`. So you can set the logcat filters to:

```
message:MainActivity -tag:ActivityManager
```

You could get very detailed with regexps and negative lookahead, but there is no longer as much need for that as there used to be.

Be careful though of how you combine these filters. There are [implicit logical operators](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat#implicit-logical-operators) which could be AND or OR, depending on what the Logcat window thinks you mean. In other words, the interpretation is typically right, but can sometimes surprise you, unless you make your operators explicit:

```
message:MainActivity & -tag:ActivityManager
```